# scroll with css property webkit-overflow-scrolling is too fast on Android

Tags: android, css, scroll, touch

I use the property `webkit-overflow-scrolling` to render a scrollview on a part of my webapp, for touch devices.

The issue is that, my scroll is really fast, and we can scroll a long element, with only one fast fling, and the scroll is very difficult to control. On iOs 7, the scroll is ok.

the code of my element :

```
.touch-scroll{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```